# Instructions for these two LEGO bags?

Tags: set-identification, instructions

Looking for some help. Christmas morning was a blur, and we ended up with two LEGO bags with no matching instructions. Can you all help identify the contents and correlating instructions? [image: bags]

Comment: that's is from set set 11018-1

Answer (score 4):

Both bags appear to be from set [11018 - Creative Ocean Fun](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11018-1)

[image]

Building instructions are available from Lego customer service [here](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/11018).